# Tex Live Utility via wget.x86_64-darwin is not signed

Tags: mactex, tlmgr

I installed the 2017 Tex package earlier this year and I have managed to update using Tex Live Utility without any issues thus far.

I just lately installed Little Snitch and it flagged the mirror via wget.x86_64-darwin and the explanation was that the mirror does not have a valid signature whilst Tex Live Utility itself has a valid signature and so the rule requires a valid signature on both the process's.

Any suggestions as to how I should proceed?

Edit's:

I am on a iMac OS High Sierra Version 10.13.3

I edited the second paragraph and hopefully it is gives a better description of the issue than the unedited second paragraph did.

Here is the warning I got from Little Snitch:

TeX Live Utility via wget.x86_64-darwin
want to connect to mirror.ctan.org

Caution: "wget.x86_64-darwin" has no code signature. The executable can be maliciously modified without being detected. The matching rule is therefore not being applied.

A matching rule exists that requires a valid code signature of "TeX Live Utility", but it does not explicitly specify a requirement for the via process(in this case, "wget.x86_64-darwin"). The rules is therefore only applied if the via process's signature is also valid.

TeX live Utility has a valid code signature, but "wget.x86_64-darwin" does not. The matching rule is therefore not applied.

I could write a new rule for TeX Live Utility via wget.x86_64-darwin that ignores any code signature but I am reluctant to do that since the Little Snitch warning is clear that, that would be less secure.

Not having sufficient confidence to overwrite the existing rule is maybe a reflection of my paranoia of corrupting my files and even my computer.

Little Snitch Network Monitor.log

Here is the relevant log pertaining to wget.x86_64-darwin:

2018-02-01 14:00:19.638 Little Snitch Network Monitor[530:4903] Error loading external Internet Access Policy for bundle: /usr/local/texlive/2017/tlpkg/installer/wget/wget.x86_64-darwin: Code signatue of bundle is not valid: /usr/local/texlive/2017/tlpkg/installer/wget/wget.x86_64-darwin

Comment: I'm afraid the sentence "I just lately installed Little Snitch and it denies access to the via wget.x86_64-darwin since it does not have a valid signature whilst Tex Live Utility has a valid signature" is nearly incomprehensible. One or more words seem to be missing, for sure. Please rephrase, preferably less tersely.

Comment: How could a programme on your computer flag a mirror? Assuming your computer is not doing the mirroring and you don't have write access, that seems impossible. And what do you mean that it flagged it 'via wget.x86_64-darwin'? I assume that the latter is a binary `wget`, compiled for 64 bit x86 architecture running whatever version of Darwin is the basis for OS X 10.13.3. But that leaves me none the wiser. A link to information about Little Snitch would help, but not a lot - I know what Little Snitch does (vaguely) and I still don't understand your question.

Comment: Doesn't it let you grant an exception? I don't see how a mirror could have a signature. Usually, files have signatures (binaries, archives, documents etc.). And the mirror is not a process. My best guess is that something doesn't have a signature and Little Snitch won't let whatever it is contact the mirror for that reason. But what doesn't have a signature? The `wget` binary? Something else?

Comment: Thank you for your patience ... I will have to do some more digging to get you the information you asked for so that my question is a lot clearer ... clearly I do not understand it in the depth necessary to articulate it so that it make sense.

Comment: I think you've misread something somewhere and it has got muddled. If Little Snitch gives you an error or warning, please post the exact text of the message. Also, if LS keeps a log file, post the relevant part of that log. Posting verbatim stuff is key to getting effective help when out of your depth. I have a GPU hang of some sort and had no idea at all what the code I managed to dump to file meant, but I reported the bug with a copy of the dump, somebody recognised the problem and now I know that a fix is somewhere in the pipeline. (Hopefully, I'll even get the fix soon!)

Comment: TeX Live Utility is just a pretty GUI wrapper around `tlmgr` which itself uses other utilities to connect to mirrors and download packages. You should therefore expect this complaint from Little Snitch. At least, as far as I can tell reading Little Snitch's blurb. Note that the purpose of Little Snitch is not to ensure the integrity of binaries (which it does not do), but to control the flow of information from your machine to the net. The way something like `tlmgr` works is to use other things to do the connecting. So, unlike something like Safari, allowing the `tlmgr` binary isn't enough.

Comment: I don't know how the code signatures work. I know OS X apps now are signed or something like that. But I doubt very much that binaries such as `curl` and `ls` are. However, I could just be wrong about that. It is a long time since I used OS X. Little Snitch is going to make your life hell unless you think in terms not of maximising your privacy, but of managing acceptable levels of risk. Maximising privacy means you don't connect to the net. Period. And do remember that Little Snitch is about privacy of information. It's a targeted solution for a specific issue. It doesn't secure your machine.

Comment: I sign TeX Live Utility and all binaries I include with it. However, the binaries such as `wget` shipped with MacTeX/TeX Live are not code signed and probably never will be, unlike tools shipped with the OS. Note that `wget` is a fallback when direct downloading in `tlmgr` fails, so you might also see warnings about `tlmgr` being unsigned. Or perhaps not, since `/usr/bin/perl` is codesigned; I don't use Little Snitch, so I'm not familiar with how it checks.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I will allow the connection since your explanation has helped me make a more balanced decision.

Comment: Can’t you open Little Snitch Configuration and tell Little Snitch that wget.x86_64-darwin is ok?

Comment: For context, @cfr, `curl` et al. are, indeed, codesigned, as shipped with macOS. `wget`, however, is not, as the user presumably installed it with Homebrew or similar: `codesign -dv --verbose=4 /usr/{bin/curl,local/bin/wget}`. Also, the original wording, with the strange placement of "via" in the original question is straight out of Little Snitch — it's a domain thing, not @railsdancer being an idiot! 

Comment: Re: the original question; I suggest you ask for more information on https://security.stackexchange.com, if you're really curious — but unless @AdamMaxwell restricts himself to using only macOS-shipped tools (like `curl` instead of `wget`), or unless the entire Linux community adopts the codesigning practices that are becoming common macOS-side, you'd better start getting used to seeing those messages when doing Software Development Things. 

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE They were random examples. I didn't know what OS X hand. (Though I did know it had `ls`, so I should have substituted something else there.) OS X has nothing to do with Linux development. It is not based on Linux. (It could not be based on Linux.) It's based on Free BSD. And even things like `ls` differ between Linux and BSD in many cases. (I used to have GNU `ls`, which Apple obviously can't use, installed as `gls`, which is what I was thinking of.)

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE It isn't AdamMaxwell's call. TLU is a wrapper around `tlmgr`. It is `tlmgr` which calls `perl`'s `LWP` module (preferably) or `wget` (otherwise). See the man page for details. Note also that Linux doesn't include `ls` or `curl` or `wget`. It is just the kernel. `ls` is from GNU, who also supply `wget`. `curl` is a separate project, I think.